# See how long a transaction took to confirm

Tags: transactions, block-interval

Given a finalized transaction, is there a way to see how long it took? Perhaps using blocks to calculate an estimate?

Take [this one](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x173fd250d63a62bb407f214ff924b49e1c90593572eab1a8c523783f2aa58ba3) for instance.

I have been trying to calculate transaction times of existing ones but I feel I'm missing some info and I dont know whether these sites are showing the most relevant information or that is all there is to a transaction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no exact way to see how much a transaction takes to be mined. The transaction can float around in the network for a few hours, be discarded by the nodes and can be republished again (identical transaction) to the network and be mined.

There is no timestamp attached to the transaction when it is first published or created.

What you can do is create a service that connects to an ethereum node (geth / parity) and monitor transactions by hash, save them in a database and see when they were added in blocks.

You can run a parity node with

```
--tx-queue-gas off
--tx-queue-mem-limit 0
--tx-queue-size 18446744073709551615
```

Which will increase to max the number of transactions that are added to the pool. By default some are ignored

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the accepted answer, if you're running a full node, you can monitor transactions as they're added to the transaction pool, take a note of the time that they appear<sup>1</sup>, then compare against the time at which they eventually get incorporated into a block.

This is likely how services such as ETH Gas Station's [TxPool Report](https://ethgasstation.info/txPoolReport.php) work.

<sup>1</sup> Handling for the case in which they're removed from the pool and resubmitted.

Comment: You don't need a full node to monitor transactions

Comment: You might be right - I've never checked for a service provides access to its transaction pool :-) Also, if you're running your own node, you'd need to ensure your transaction pool config was such that you could be certain you were storing all broadcast transactions, which might also be difficult to do without a large amount of RAM.

Comment: I've added more information about how to run a node to monitor the tx pool. I'm currently running a node that has other optimizations in place, like decreasing ancient blocks that are saved in the database, disabling ui, ... but those specific parameters allow you to monitor almost all transactions floating in the network

Comment: Yep, I've done this in the past, it's just I thought a full node was required to do this - are you saying it's possible to do this on Parity with pruning enabled? (i.e. The transaction pool is running even if you're not a full archive node.)

Comment: Yes, it works with pruning enabled. Not sure if you consider this a full node or not :)

Comment: Aha - thanks for the info - wasn't sure how Parity worked in this respect :-)